# Use Case Diagrams - can actors be within system boundary?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am developing a software in Java which will run a TFTP Client created as a part of the software and will connect to a TFTP Server which will be external.

My question is should I have the TFTP Client as an actor inside the system boundary using the Actor symbol, as this is something that the system will do? or should I leave it outside the system boundary?

Answer (score 1):

Actors are by definition the things outside of your system with which your system interacts.

So an Actor inside your system boundary would be a *contradictio in terminis*

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your abstraction level. It is well possible to define actors inside the system under consideration which you represent as the *main* boundary. Usually if you introduce such actors inside it means that you have sub-systems where those actors interact. So in your case the TFTP is such a sub-system.